# Difference between normal JDBC and JDBCIO connector in apache Beam?

Tags: jdbc, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Being a beginner with the Apache Beam programming model, I would like to know what is the difference between `JDBC` and `jdbcio`. I have developed a simple dataflow which involves normal `JDBC` connection and it is working as expected.

Is it mandatory to use `jdbcio` over `JDBC`? If yes, what are the issues we face when we go with a normal `JDBC` code?

Comment: What's normal JDBC?

Comment: Are you using the JDBC connection to read in your PCollection, or are you using it within a DoFn to enrich a element flowing through your pipeline?

Comment: @RezaRokni I am using jdbc inside DoFn. Basically I would like to understand the advantages of using jdbcio over jdbc.If I go with plain old jdbc code inside DoFn, what are the challenges that i face with it?

Comment: @RuiWang, i just referred plain java jdbc code as normal jdbc in this context.

Comment: In your DoFn do you make use of a property of the data element in your call out? For example calling the db using a predicate which makes use of one of the properties of the element.
Also are you intending this to be used for streaming or batch processing?

Comment: @RezaRokni It is a streaming job. In simple terms in my DoFn, i first established a synchronized jdbc connection following by my pojo's which are mapped to c.element and executing all database operations.

Answer (score 4):

Within a Beam pipeline there are various options for reading and writing out to external sources of data. The most common method is to make use of inbuilt sinks and sources that have been built by the Beam community (Built-in I/O Transforms). These connectors will often have had considerable development effort spent on them and will have been production hardened. For example the BigQueryIO has been used in production for many years, with continuous development throughout that period. The general advice will therefore be to make use of the standard Sinks and Sources whenever possible.

However not all interactions with external data sources should be via Sources and Sinks, there are use cases where a hand built communication from a DoFn to the external source is the correct path. A few examples below (there are more of course!);

- There is no Sink / Source to the data source, or there is a source
  but it does not yet support all switches / modes etc for your needs.
  Of course you can always enhance the existing Sink / Source or if it
  does not exist to build a new I/O connector from scratch and if
  possible would be great to contribute this back to the community :)
- You are enriching elements flowing through your streaming pipeline
  with a small subset of data from a large data set. For example, let's
  say your processing events coming from a sales order and you would
  like to add information for each item. The information for the item's
  lives in a large multi TB store but on average you will only access a
  small percentage of the data as lookup keys. In this example it makes
  sense to enrich each element by making an external call to the data
  store within a DoFn. Rather than reading all of the data in as a
  Source and doing the join operation within the pipeline.

Extra notes / hints:

When calling external systems, keep in mind that Apache Beam is designed to distribute work across many threads, this can place significant load on your external datasource, you can often reduce this load by making use of the start & end bundle annotations;

Java (SDK 2.9.0)

- DoFn.StartBundle
- DoFn.FinishBundle

Python (SDK 2.9.0)

- start_bundle()
- finish_bundle()

Comment: Thankyou so much for this important piece of information. I tried implementing the DoFn.startbundle concept for streaming job. But When i ran the job with 100 million records of data. It is spinning upto 56 worker nodes, because of which i had to stop the job. Is there any way to optimize the database connection which is inside startbundle so that it is performance effective rather than using jdbcio connector.

Comment: The blog is a little dated but should still be useful: 

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/guide-to-common-cloud-dataflow-use-case-patterns-part-1

Look for following pattern Calling external services for data enrichment. 
If you can ask this is a new question I will try and get time to give a updated answer..